# What does "Such methods are inherited unless they are overridden" means

Tags: testing, junit5

When JUnit5 explain @Test, the doc https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations said

> Such methods are inherited unless they are overridden

What does this sentence means? I not see anything related to method inheritance at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that if you have a test class `A`, in which you define a method `test` annotated with `@Test`, JUnit will execute `test` also in a test class `B` that inherits `A`. This does not apply if you override `test` in class `B`.

**Example:**

```
public class A {
  @Test
  public void testA() {
    // ...
  }

  @Test
  public void testB() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

```
public class B extends A {
  @Override
  public void testB() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

When executing test class `A`, `testA` and `testB` will be executed. When executing `B`, `testA` is inherited and will be executed. However, `testB` is overridden and not annotated with `@Test` and will not get executed.

Comment: Thank you for the detail explain, accept it